# Discord bot cannot play audio and throwing VoiceChannel.AuthenticationFailed error

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, voice

I recently have this problem when trying to start my discord bot which is using discord JS 12.5.3, the console throwing VoiceChannel.AuthenticationFailed, the bot already joined the channel but the bot doesn't play the audio here the code

`let language = args[0]
if(langlist.find(c => c === language)) {
if(!language) return message.reply("Please enter the language")

```
if(!args[1]) return message.reply("Please enter the text")
const text = args.slice(1).join(" ")
if(text.length > 200) return message.reply('You cant input a text with over 200 characters')
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
if(!voiceChannel) return message.reply(" Please enter a voice channel") 

                                    
const audioURL = await getAudioUrl(text, {
    lang: language, 
    slow: false, 
    host: 'https://translate.google.com', 
    timeout: '150000'
})


try {
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
        const dispatcher = connection.play(audioURL)
        dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        setTimeout(() => voiceChannel.leave(), 2 * 50 * 1000)
        })
    })
}
catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    message.channel.send("A Problem Occured When Trying To Play The Sound, Try Again Later...")
}`
```

I tried checking the channel permission and bot invite permission but not worked, the bot permission is on 8 which is administrator but it keeps throwing voice authentication failed

Comment: Update discord.js to latest version (v14)